# python virtualenv from terminal not working but working from pycharm

Tags: python, virtualenv

Python3 showing error while trying to create a new virtual environment from **terminal** using

```
virtualenv name_goes_here
```

with error,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/w3e/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in 
> from virtualenv import main
> ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv/**init**.py)

But it works when I do it from **PyCharm > Settings > Project Interpreter > Add Python Interpreter**
See the attached image below-

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating your virtual environment using builtin `venv` module?

Comment: No I didn't try with `venv`

Comment: I think pycharm uses `venv` to create the environment because `virtualenv` is a 3rd party tool.

Comment: In case you don't know, the command is `python3 -m venv name_goes_here`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you were using doesn't exist.

Try this instead:

```
python3 -m venv your_venv
```

And activate it using:

```
source your_venv/Scripts/activate
```